# Flavor based localizing - Android

Tags: android, localization, localizable.strings

I have set up my application with different string files for different languages English(default)/French/Arabic.

When I change the language on the device, it stays in English.

Here is my project layout:

```
--src
  |__main
    |__res
      |__values-ar
      |__values-fr
      |__values
   |__variants
     |__flavour1
       |__res
         |__values-ar
         |__values-fr
         |__values
     |__flavour2
       |__res
         |__values-ar
         |__values-fr
         |__values
     |__flavour3
       |__res
         |__values-ar
         |__values-fr
         |__values
```

The device is now displaying french after switching the language to french in the settings but the application is still displaying English.

Can anyone help?

Comment: are you using strings from resources  correctly ?

Comment: @Murtaza In my layout files, I'm setting them from the string folder e.g. `android:text="@string/createNewUser"`  Is that what you mean?

Comment: so that's correct, do you have any other ideas?

Comment: do you switch language on your code or device ?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain  I have switched the language on the device to French and I have values-fr file but it's not working.  Could the flavours have something to do with it?

Comment: I don't think so. but give it a try

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain  give what a try?  I'm wondering if my project structure is correct, as I have flavours introduced.  Does it look correct?

Comment: it is correct, nothing wrong with  your project structure. Give a try to by removing flavors and check if it works.

Comment: Seems like your project structure do have a problem, check my answer

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain removing the flavours, the problem still exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-src
  |__main
    |__res
      |__values-ar
      |__values-fr
      |__values
   |__variants   < ------ Remove this 
     |__flavour1
       |__res
         |__values-ar
         |__values-fr
         |__values
     |__flavour2
       |__res
         |__values-ar
         |__values-fr
         |__values
     |__flavour3
       |__res
         |__values-ar
         |__values-fr
         |__values
```

After

```
-src
      |__main
        |__res
          |__values-ar
          |__values-fr
          |__values

       |__flavour1
         |__res
           |__values-ar
           |__values-fr
           |__values
       |__flavour2
         |__res
           |__values-ar
           |__values-fr
           |__values
       |__flavour3
         |__res
           |__values-ar
           |__values-fr
           |__values
```